# Rails 4 assets.precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

This is a common question in here, but none of the solutions fixed my problem, so here it goes:

I am adding ace.js to my rails4 app, So what I did was

```
- Added vendor/assets/ace/ace.js
- Created vendor/assets/ace/index.js , with content
  //= require ace  
- Added the following to my production.rb
  config.assets.precompile += %w( index.js )  
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "ace")
```

So in my layout file I have:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "ace" %>
```

and it works just fine on dev, but when I run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

It doest not create the digest version of the ace file.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is solved by adding :

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( index.js )
```

to `config/application.rb`. (not `config/environments/production.rb`)

Tested in Rails 4.0 beta1.

Comment: Thanks this really helped me.  Was this a change in Rails 4?  It users to be in `production.rb` but the docs aren't clear in pointing out that this is now supposed to be set in `application.rb'

Comment: Is there a way to do this without specifying every individual file?

Comment: @ahnbizcad This *might* work:  `config.assets.precompile += [/(^[^_\/]|\/[^_])[^\/]*$/]`

Answer (score 2):

In case you are adding the `ace` directory as an assets , you should place the `js` files under `vendor/assets/ace/javascripts` directory (which you should create) .

Normally you don't need `config.assets.precompile += %w( index.js )`, Sprockets will manage it just fine. If there is just one js file to add from `vendors/assets/ace` directory , you don't need an index.js there . The `index.js` would be proper if you have a lot of subdirectories and files under `vendor/assets/ace/javascripts/your_vendor_js_library` . One last touch : you don't need `<%= javascript_include_tag "ace" %>` , it duplicates `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`'s content.

Comment: So when I precompile, will it create a application-xxx.js and ace-xxx.js files?

Comment: I think the file will be only one - `application-xxx.css` .That's the reason behind precompilling assets.

Comment: The idea for combining the assets in one optimized file is to decrease server hits. What would be the reason for splitting assets ?[A nice reference about the theory](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: I need to slip them, because the ace.js is big and will be used in 10$ of the screens only.

Comment: You can load assets per controller , it it fits in your case.