# Rails 4 Assets Precompilation with multiple manifest files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails 4 application.

I have 3 sets of manifest files in order to seperate out logic for my app.

These files are

```
application.js
backoffice.js
pos.js

application.css
backoffice.css
pos.css
```

In my layout files, I reference these assets using the associated javascript_link_tags

I have added the following to my production.rb file (in order to include these files in the precompilation of assets):

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( backoffice.js pos.js pos.css backoffice.css )
```

I then run rake assets:precompile, but it is not picking up the additional files. 
It only compiles the application.js and application.css manifests.

In production.rb also, I have:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = false
```

Anyone any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you copy this line

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( backoffice.js pos.js pos.css backoffice.css )
```

to `config/application.rb` (Rails 4.0) (instead of `config/environments/production.rb`) it will work.

I've got a tip from here: [Rails 4 assets.precompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882337/rails-4-assets-precompile)

As suggested in the comments, in **Rails 4.2** you should write above line in `config/initializers/assets.rb`

Comment: This could be a bug in rails 4?

Comment: Can / should that code go into `config/initializers/assets.rb`?

Comment: @gwho Yes, in Rails 4.2 that snippet is now put into that initializer when one does `rails new`.