# Javascript does not work from a bootstrap template in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a new rails app and installed all the necessary gems. Added all the files. Updated the application.js file. Everything works but for some reason all the javascript related things do not work. Im using this template:

https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/

Im using also a partial for the navigationbar.
What am I missing? If you need further information just let me know!

app/assets/javascripts/**application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require magnific-popup
//= require welcomes
//= require jquery.easing
//= require scrollReveal
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'scrollreveal-rails'
gem 'magnific-popup-rails', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'jquery-easing-rails'

gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'bootstrap-sass'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

app/assets/javascripts/**welcomes.js**

```
(function($) {
    "use strict"; // Start of use strict

    // jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50)
        }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
        offset: 51
    });

    // Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
    $('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
        $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
    });

    // Offset for Main Navigation
    $('#mainNav').affix({
        offset: {
            top: 100
        }
    })

    // Initialize and Configure Scroll Reveal Animation
    window.sr = ScrollReveal();
    sr.reveal('.sr-icons', {
        duration: 600,
        scale: 0.3,
        distance: '0px'
    }, 200);
    sr.reveal('.sr-button', {
        duration: 1000,
        delay: 200
    });
    sr.reveal('.sr-contact', {
        duration: 600,
        scale: 0.3,
        distance: '0px'
    }, 300);

    // Initialize and Configure Magnific Popup Lightbox Plugin
    $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'image',
        tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true,
            navigateByImgClick: true,
            preload: [0, 1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
        },
        image: {
            tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.'
        }
    });

})(jQuery); // End of use strict
```

**_header.html.erb**

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<header>
  <div class="header-content">

    <div class="header-content-inner">
      <h1 id="homeHeading">Your Favorite Source of Free Bootstrap Themes</h1>
      <hr>
      <p>Start Bootstrap can help you build better websites using the Bootstrap CSS framework! Just download your template and start going, no strings attached!</p>
      <a href="#about" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll">Find Out More</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<section class="bg-primary" id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
          <h2 class="section-heading">We've got what you need!</h2>
          <hr class="light">
          <p class="text-faded">Start Bootstrap has everything you need to get your new website up and running in no time! All of the templates and themes on Start Bootstrap are open source, free to download, and easy to use. No strings attached!</p>
          <a href="#services" class="page-scroll btn btn-default btn-xl sr-button">Get Started!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="services">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="section-heading">At Your Service</h2>
        <hr class="primary">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
        <div class="service-box">
          <i class="fa fa-4x fa-diamond text-primary sr-icons"></i>
          <h3>Sturdy Templates</h3>
          <p class="text-muted">Our templates are updated regularly so they don't break.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
        <div class="service-box">
          <i class="fa fa-4x fa-paper-plane text-primary sr-icons"></i>
          <h3>Ready to Ship</h3>
          <p class="text-muted">You can use this theme as is, or you can make changes!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
        <div class="service-box">
          <i class="fa fa-4x fa-newspaper-o text-primary sr-icons"></i>
          <h3>Up to Date</h3>
          <p class="text-muted">We update dependencies to keep things fresh.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
        <div class="service-box">
          <i class="fa fa-4x fa-heart text-primary sr-icons"></i>
          <h3>Made with Love</h3>
          <p class="text-muted">You have to make your websites with love these days!</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</section>

<section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter popup-gallery">

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/1.jpg" class="portfolio-box">
          <%= image_tag("1.jpg", alt: "#", :class => "img-responsive") %>
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
              <div class="project-category text-faded">
                Category
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Project Name
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/2.jpg" class="portfolio-box">
          <%= image_tag("2.jpg", alt: "#", :class => "img-responsive") %>
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
              <div class="project-category text-faded">
                Category
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Project Name
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/3.jpg" class="portfolio-box">
          <%= image_tag("3.jpg", alt: "#", :class => "img-responsive") %>
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
              <div class="project-category text-faded">
                Category
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Project Name
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/4.jpg" class="portfolio-box">
          <%= image_tag("4.jpg", alt: "#", :class => "img-responsive") %>
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
              <div class="project-category text-faded">
                Category
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Project Name
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/5.jpg" class="portfolio-box">
          <%= image_tag("5.jpg", alt: "#", :class => "img-responsive") %>
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
              <div class="project-category text-faded">
                Category
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Project Name
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/6.jpg" class="portfolio-box">
          <%= image_tag("6.jpg", alt: "#", :class => "img-responsive") %>
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
              <div class="project-category text-faded">
                Category
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Project Name
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<aside class="bg-dark">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="call-to-action">
      <h2>Free Download at Start Bootstrap!</h2>
      <a href="http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/" class="btn btn-default btn-xl sr-button">Download Now!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>

<section id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
        <h2 class="section-heading">Let's Get In Touch!</h2>
        <hr class="primary">
        <p>Ready to start your next project with us? That's great! Give us a call or send us an email and we will get back to you as soon as possible!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
        <i class="fa fa-phone fa-3x sr-contact"></i>
        <p>123-456-6789</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-3x sr-contact"></i>
        <p><a href="mailto:your-email@your-domain.com">feedback@startbootstrap.com</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Template</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
<body>

<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<%= yield %>
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>

</body>
</html>
```

**application.css.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "jquery-ui/all";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "magnific-popup";

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}

hr {
  border-color: #F05F40;
  border-width: 3px;
  max-width: 50px;
}

hr.light {
  border-color: white;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  color: #F05F40;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #eb3812;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bg-primary {
  background-color: #F05F40;
}

.bg-dark {
  background-color: #222222;
  color: white;
}

.text-faded {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

section {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

aside {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.05);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  color: #F05F40;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #eb3812;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #222222;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li > a,
.navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #222222;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus:hover {
  color: #F05F40;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a,
.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #F05F40 !important;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a:focus:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: white;
  }

  .navbar-default .nav > li > a,
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }

  .navbar-default .nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus:hover {
    color: white;
  }

  .navbar-default.affix {
    background-color: white;
    border-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.05);
  }

  .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: #F05F40;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #eb3812;
  }

  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a,
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #222222;
  }

  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a:focus:hover {
    color: #F05F40;
  }

}

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: auto;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: asset-data-url("header.jpg");
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

header .header-content {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px 15px 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner hr {
  margin: 30px auto;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  header {
    min-height: 100%;
  }

  header .header-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding: 0 50px;
  }

  header .header-content .header-content-inner {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
  }

  header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
    font-size: 18px;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

}

.section-heading {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.service-box {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

  .service-box {
    margin: 20px auto 0;
  }

}

.service-box p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.portfolio-box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption {
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(240, 95, 64, 0.9);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category,
.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.portfolio-box:hover .portfolio-box-caption {
  opacity: 1;
}

.portfolio-box:focus {
  outline: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
    font-size: 22px;
  }

}

.call-to-action h2 {
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

.text-primary {
  color: #F05F40;
}

.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.btn-default {
  color: #222222;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default.focus,
.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
  color: #222222;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-color: #ededed;
}

.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
  background-image: none;
}

.btn-default.disabled,
.btn-default[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default,
.btn-default.disabled:hover,
.btn-default[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:hover,
.btn-default.disabled:focus,
.btn-default[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:focus,
.btn-default.disabled.focus,
.btn-default[disabled].focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.focus,
.btn-default.disabled:active,
.btn-default[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:active,
.btn-default.disabled.active,
.btn-default[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.active {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;
}

.btn-default .badge {
  color: white;
  background-color: #222222;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: white;
  background-color: #F05F40;
  border-color: #F05F40;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ee4b28;
  border-color: #ed431f;
}

.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  background-image: none;
}

.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn-primary[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary,
.btn-primary.disabled:hover,
.btn-primary[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary.disabled:focus,
.btn-primary[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.disabled.focus,
.btn-primary[disabled].focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary.disabled:active,
.btn-primary[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.disabled.active,
.btn-primary[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.active {
  background-color: #F05F40;
  border-color: #F05F40;
}

.btn-primary .badge {
  color: #F05F40;
  background-color: white;
}

.btn {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 300px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-xl {
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

::-moz-selection {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #222222;
}

::selection {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #222222;
}

img::selection {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
}

img::-moz-selection {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
}

body {
  webkit-tap-highlight-color: #222222;
}
```

Comment: Probably just a misprint. You meant /app/assets/javascripts (with an 's'), right?

Comment: @DmitryKukhlevsky yes i misprint it! ;)

Comment: Do you see javascripts included in the html page when using developers mode in browser? (or when viewing source of the page)

Comment: @DmitryKukhlevsky No when I use developer tools in chrome and look into the console it is empty

Comment: Please post yout layout file then. It is probably missing javascript_include_tag 'application'

Comment: @DmitryKukhlevsky Its actually inside... I have updated the layout file! Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: @trickydiddy actually I had a lot of problems with this, there are a couple or reasons your layout file could not get compiled, but in the end I was able to fix the problems.. in the end did you understand what was the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally managed to make it work! First of all I started from new and I created a new rails app because I was in desperate mode and installed to many Gems and changed the code that at the end the code was a mess.

This time I took a different approach and I did not use any additional gems and I have installed all the necessary plugins manually meaning just copy and paste all the files in the correct directories and linking them together.
I had to delete the coffeescript file inside the javascript directory becuase the file caused some issues. As you can see I also had to put a trigger manually inside the body tag otherwise the ScrollSpy function would not work (data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top"). For some reason Javascript still did not work but I have read that Javascript/jQuery can cause some issues if its not loaded properly meaning in the correct oder. So I deleted //= require_tree . in the javascript file. And put each javascript in the correct order. I could figure out the correct oder by looking at the source code of the working template. But it still did not work! I then put the "<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>" at the very end of the  tag so the javascript would load last. ... And finally it worked! My next step would be to delete the turbolinks line in the application.js file and I would change:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

into

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
```

Because I have read that turbolinks can cause some issues with the asset pipeline with javascript especially.

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Creativetemplate</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  </head>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <%= yield %>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.easing
//= require scrollreveal
//= require jquery.magnific-popup
//= require welcomes
```

**welcomes.js**

```
(function($) {
    "use strict"; // Start of use strict
    // debugger
    // jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50)
        }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
        offset: 51
    });

    // Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
    $('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
        $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
    });

    // Offset for Main Navigation
    $('#mainNav').affix({
        offset: {
            top: 100
        }
    })

    // Initialize and Configure Scroll Reveal Animation
    window.sr = ScrollReveal();
    sr.reveal('.sr-icons', {
        duration: 600,
        scale: 0.3,
        distance: '0px'
    }, 200);
    sr.reveal('.sr-button', {
        duration: 1000,
        delay: 200
    });
    sr.reveal('.sr-contact', {
        duration: 600,
        scale: 0.3,
        distance: '0px'
    }, 300);

    // Initialize and Configure Magnific Popup Lightbox Plugin
    $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'image',
        tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true,
            navigateByImgClick: true,
            preload: [0, 1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
        },
        image: {
            tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.'
        }
    });

})(jQuery); // End of use strict
```

**application.css.scss**

```
/*
*= require magnific-popup
*= require welcomes
*/

@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

...
...
...
```

If someone has similar issues with Javascript and the Asset Pipeline this is how I would try to solve it:

**1)** Make sure that all the files are in the correct directory

**2)** Check if all the files are correctly linked together inside the application.css.scss, application.js and application.html.erb

**3)** Delete the "//= require_tree ." line in application.js because it loads the javascript with no specific order and it could create some issues. Type every line manually in the correct order of the theme. You can check the correct oder by looking at the source code of the template in the browser.

**4)** Check if the correct version number of the plugins are installed by comparing the source code when you run your localserver and check the website with the template website.

**5)** If you don't need the coffeescript file in the javascript directory then delete it.

**6)** Move the "javascript_include_tag" from inside the head tag right above the closing body tag. So the javascript can get loaded last.

**7)** Get rid of turbolinks in application.js and application.html.erb.

**8)** If it still does not work check the Developer Tools(Console) in Chrome of the website and you can use also a debugger in the javascript file to see if there are any errors.

Hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: actually **point 5** solved my problem. My `app/assets/javascript` folder had a `user.coffee` file automatically generated, which was empty and was being loaded instead of the `user.js` file. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I am editing my answer, because I still had problems with the Asset Pipeline.

I add the following resources that may help in finding a solution and I will post the solution to the problem once I solved it.

https://launchschool.com/blog/rails-asset-pipeline-best-practices

https://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html

https://reinteractive.com/posts/116-12-tips-for-the-rails-asset-pipeline

I read all the guides that can be found by searching rails asset pipeline, but I will not link them all

My advice is to check the fingerprint of the application.css and application.js both with the Chrome Developer Tools (by going in any screen element, opening the developer toolbox with f12 and checking any style of any div or any js file). You will need to check which fingerprint version of the file is used, then open that version with the text editor and check what is loaded in the fingerprint version of the file.

If your file (for ex. user.js) is loaded at the bottom of the manifest, you should easily find it at the bottom of your fingerprinted application.js.

If you want to update this file you can run

`rake assets:precompile`

This will precompile assets only in development, for production you need to specify the environment. It will change that fingerprinted file application.css and application.js with the editing you have done.

You can also check the file at the following address `localhost:3000/assets/yourjsfile.js` or check the fingerprint version by following `localhost:3000/assets/application-yourfingerprint.js`

As you can see, many files are included in that public/assets folder, you can delete them with `rake assets:clean` or `-rf public/assets` and then run `rake assets:precompile`, it will precompile again assets.

If nothing is included, then your application.js is not being loaded. You may try the following as I read on different posts:

1. Include the file in the `config/initializers/assets.rb` with the following line of code:

   ```
   Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( user.js )
   ```
2. Start the `rails c` and run `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`
   This command will show in red the paths that are automatically included, for example those inside App, Lib and Vendor, in green those that you included by adding inside `config/application.rb` the follwing code to add new path

   ```
   config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor","assets", "fonts")
   ```

Another error i made in the past was not using the correct sprockets syntax, you can check it at the following link ( i was using require_user instead of require user):

https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives

My problem was that I had under App/assets/javascript two files named user (user.coffee and user.js). The first to be loaded was user.coffee which was empty. 
I found the solution thanks to the answer of **trickydiddy**

Comment: Thanks this will help me! Is javascript working in your website? I think you don't need the <%= stylesheet_link_tag in the application.html.erb file since Rails 4. I think the association in the application.js file should be sufficient if you have put a working javascript file in assets/javascrips/filename.js

Comment: Yes, I just tested. I have Rails 5 and I downgraded to 'sprockets-rails' '2.3.3'.

Comment: @trickydiddy The problem is that when I run my server, I have a get request for every css, js and img in my terminal log, so right now I will update sprockets and read carefully the asset pipeline to get it working correctly. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: @trickydiddy hi, i edited my post, you can review it and maybe you could check if http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js and post the result. This discussion could help you find a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168166/rails-4-assets-precompilation-with-multiple-manifest-files#16168455

Comment: Thank you I finally made it work I posted an answer if you are curious u can check it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is around the `welcomes.js` and the turbolinks.
Convert your `welcomes.js` to coffee (with [js2coffee](http://js2.coffee/) for example) and then copy it in a file like `home.coffee` on your `app/assets/javascripts`.
The **key** is at the first line to add `$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->`

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  (($) ->
    'use strict'
    # Start of use strict
    # jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
    $('a.page-scroll').bind 'click', (event) ->
      $anchor = $(this)
      $('html, body').stop().animate { scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50 }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo'
      event.preventDefault()
      return
    # Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
    $('body').scrollspy
      target: '.navbar-fixed-top'
      offset: 51
    # Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
    $('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click ->
      $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click()
      return
    # Offset for Main Navigation
    $('#mainNav').affix offset: top: 100
    # Initialize and Configure Scroll Reveal Animation
    window.sr = ScrollReveal()
    sr.reveal '.sr-icons', {
      duration: 600
      scale: 0.3
      distance: '0px'
    }, 200
    sr.reveal '.sr-button',
      duration: 1000
      delay: 200
    sr.reveal '.sr-contact', {
      duration: 600
      scale: 0.3
      distance: '0px'
    }, 300
    # Initialize and Configure Magnific Popup Lightbox Plugin
    $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup
      delegate: 'a'
      type: 'image'
      tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...'
      mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile'
      gallery:
        enabled: true
        navigateByImgClick: true
        preload: [
          0
          1
        ]
      image: tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.'
    return
  ) jQuery
```

and everything works fine!
Don't change anything else. Setup your js manifest with the correct js files for your template and you're ready.