# Rails and SLIM html image_tag points to images instead of assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I have a scenario where I need to send emails using a template written in SLIM. I fixed my `environment/development.rb` with the following `config` that I find necessary (also based from my research)

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( print.css )
config.serve_static_assets = true (still using Rails 4.1.16)
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'http://localhost:3000' }
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
config.action_mailer.asset_host = config.action_controller.asset_host
```

I know it's pointing correctly to my root url on this step. Then In my `mailer.html.slim` I have something like this:

```
div align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 30px;padding-bottom: 30px;float:left;"
  a href="http://#{App.url}"
      = image_tag "images/logo-old.png", style: "display:inline-block", border: "0", alt: App.name, width: 139, height: 44, title: App.name
```

I tried the following already:

```
= image_tag "logo-old.png"
= image_tag "assets/images/logo-old.png"
= image_url "logo-old.png"
```

Nothing's working but good thing its now showing the `Alt` to know its still working by its path.

The current `= image_tag` evaluates to :

```
 src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/83z0D3PVOqx-FwFFMwztfYBs5CSWHiURyxSUP6cZ3dq7Zo47k9mNPgotrijVmmWGxPHqblRTGCePqN4RrfEhHh_665
MdAQ=s0-d-e1-ft#http://localhost:3000/images/images/logo-old.png"
```

Any idea why the app can't find the normal pipeline path?
Instead of `images/images/logo-old.png` I need the `assets/images/logo-old.png`

Edit:

So for result comparison, if I do `image_url "logo-old.png"` the path results to `/assets/logo-old.png`

If I do `image_url "images/logo-old.png"` the path results to `images/images/logo-old.png`

My image is in `app/assets/images/logo-old.png`

Answer (score 0):

1) is `http://localhost:3000/images/images/logo-old.png` the correct folder structure of your `app/assets/images/images/logo-old.png` ?

2) did you add the `app/assets/images` to the asset pipeline?

[How to  add folders to asset pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#search-paths)

[Javascript does not work from a bootstrap template in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965803/javascript-does-not-work-from-a-bootstrap-template-in-rails)

3) did you check with `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` the default search paths in your `rails console`, did you try to organize correctly the images to be stored inside `app/assets/images` folder and added that folder to the asset pipeline?

then you should be able to do `image_url "logo-old.png"`

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for breaking down what I should double check. Rechecked on my `Rails.application.config.assets.path` and it does contain what I need from my project : `"/home/spotontheresa/Documents/projects/myproject/app/assets/images"` My project is also structured correctly as far as I know it's app - assets - images - the image I need /logo-old.png

Comment: Any more ideas where I should check?

Comment: @Theresa it should be using the pre-compiled asset from `public/assets` including the fingerprint, while it is falling back to the asset in your `app/assets/images` folder. This fallback behavior  can be disabled https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#raise-an-error-when-an-asset-is-not-found inside `development.rb`. The fact is you need to clear all your precompiled assets and precompile sometimes to see you changes take effect