# Rails custom layouts - routingerror in production

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have an admin section of my site that uses an 'admin' layout.

```
class Admin::BaseController < ActionController::Base
  layout "admin"
```

in layouts/admin.html.slim

```
 = stylesheet_link_tag "admin", :media => "all"
 = javascript_include_tag "admin"
```

I get an error for the admin.js and admin.css

```
Started GET "/stylesheets/admin.css" for x.x.x.x at 2013-10-25 13:18:16 +0000
F, [2013-10-25T13:18:16.505425 #31550] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/admin.css"):
```

this works perfectly in development and the frontend assets are loading normally in production, what can the problem be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 4 assets.precompile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882337/rails-4-assets-precompile)

Comment: adding 'config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.js admin.css )' to application.rb fixes the problem, though I don't know why it happens..

Comment: Added an explanation for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your rails server (webrick, thin, ...) serves your assets uncompiled, where it looks for it in several places (like `app/assets` or `vendor/assets`). In production, rails assumes that the production webserver handles asset serving, which are served from `public/`.

Since compilation on runtime – or delivering them uncompiled at all – slows down page serving, they are compiled into the name of its **known** manifest-files that reference your styles (that is `application.{css/js}` by default), which you do by invoking `rake assets:precompile`.

Add `config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.css )` to `config/application.rb` or `config/environments/production.rb` to add your `admin.css` manifest so rails know that it also has to compile that one. Then run `rake assets:precompile` (if you've put it into the later, you may need to add `RAILS_ENV=production`).

Comment: That was my problem.  Solved it with the `config.assets.precompile +=` hint.